# Run Macros based on conditions in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have tried a few ways to set up these macros. Bascially for each year there are 10 different versions of the macro, and I need to create a way to use the let statement at top to run only a single macro based on those conditions.

*What I have now:

```
%Let year=2001;
%Let Version=9;

%IF &YEAR=2000 and &Version=1 %THEN %DO;
%INCLUDE "macro location";

%ELSE %IF &YEAR=2000 and &Version=2 %THEN %DO;
%INCLUDE "macro location";
.....goes on until I get all of the macros included.
```

When I run this code it is running all of the Macros and I need it to choose the correct macro to run based on the conditions.

Comment: You talk about running a macro but instead show including a program.  What is in the program? If it is just the macro definition then you still need to call the macro.

Answer (score 1):

When used within the macro facility, your logic should work as expected.

> When used in the DATA step, the %INCLUDE statement cannot be used in
> conditional logic. However, you can use the %INCLUDE statement with
> conditional logic when used with the macro facility. For example, you
> can specify the following %IF-%THEN macro statement:

[Source](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=lestmtsglobal&docsetTarget=p1s3uhhqtscz2sn1otiatbovfn1t.htm&locale=en#n0jc23eqcysskin1lxrxvvjrs9t2)

However, there are alternative ways you can achieve the same goal.

If these macros are all compiled or stored in a single `sasautos` location, then you can call them directly and dynamically compile based off of the values of `year` and `version`:

```
options sasautos=(sasautos '/mylocation1' '/mylocation2' ...);

%if(&year = 2000 AND &version = 1) %then %do;
   %macro1;
%end;
    %else %if ...
```

Another alternative method would be to use `call execute` to conditionally execute with a `data _null_` step:

```
data _null_;
    select;
        when(&year. = 2000 AND &version. = 1) call execute('%include /mylocation/macro1.sas');
        when(&year. = 2000 AND &version. = 2) call execute('%include /mylocation2/macro2.sas');
        ....
        otherwise;
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead placing the `%include` within a conditional block, consider naming all the locations at the top and include the one that matches the parameters.

Example:

This makes the versions and locations readily available for knowing without scanning lots of code.  Requires a consistent macro variable naming scheme.

```
%let macro_2000_v1 = /mylocation/macro1.sas ;
%let macro_2000_v2 = /mylocation/macro2.sas ;
%let macro_2000_v3 = /mylocation/macro3.sas ;
%let macro_2000_v4 = /mylocation/macro4.sas ;
%let macro_2000_v5 = /mylocation/macro5.sas ;
%let macro_2001_v6 = /mylocation/macro6_ext.sas ;
%let macro_2001_v7 = /mylocation/macro7.sas ;
%let macro_2001_v8 = /mylocation/macro8.sas ;
%let macro_2001_v9 = /mylocation/macro9.sas ;
%let macro_2001_v10 = /mylocation/macro_10_validated.sas ;

%Let year=2001;
%let version=9;

%include "&&macro_&year._v&version";
```